# Add aliases for command while defining command

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

I'd like to have a command `\NewDocumentCommands` which allows for multiple commands to be defined at once using the same definition. For example:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommands { \powerset, \Powerset, \PowerSet } {} { \mathcal{P} }
\NewDocumentCommands { \mat, \bmat } { m } { \begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix} }
```

---

My naive attempt:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewDocumentCommands } { m m m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \NewDocumentCommand { ##1 } { #2 } { #3 }
      }
  }
```

This throws a `TeX capacity exceeded` error, however.

Another attempt:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand
  { \CommandNewDocument }
  { m m m }
  { \NewDocumentCommand { #3 } { #1 } { #2 } }

\NewDocumentCommand
  { \NewDocumentCommands }
  { > { \SplitList { , } } m m m }
  { \ProcessList { #1 } { \CommandNewDocument { #2 } { #3 } } }
```

This throws all sorts of errors (`Command '\s__tl_stop' already defined.`, `Invalid argument type`, and `Command '\CommandNewDocument' already defined.`)

---

I'm aware that I could just write

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand { \powerset } {} { \mathcal{P} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \Powerset } {} { \powerset }
\NewDocumentCommand { \PowerSet } {} { \powerset }
\NewDocumentCommand { \mat } { m } { \begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \bmat } { m } { \mat { #1 } }
```

or, alternatively,

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand { \powerset } {} { \mathcal{P} }
\let\Powerset\powerset
\let\PowerSet\powerset
\NewDocumentCommand { \mat } { m } { \begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix} }
\let\bmat\mat
```

However, a dedicated command `\NewDocumentCommands` seems nicer to me if many commands with multiple aliases will be defined.

Comment: To be precise, your first approach does not throw a capacity exceeded error for the "powerset" example, but only for the "bmatrix" example.

Comment: You need to double the hashes for your first approach, so `\begin{bmatrix} ##1 \end{bmatrix}`

Comment: Not a very good approach to be honest  I would use `let` or l3 equivalent which makes the code more readable and maintainable. For mat I would also define \DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{Mat} and write e.g. $H = (h_{ji}) \in
\Mat_{r \times n}(\F_2)$, muchh better in write-ups IMHO.

Comment: You should normally use \NewCommandCopy instead of \let to copy commands as that copies also the inner structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem of `#` doubling. You can also avoid setting a sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \NewDocumentCommands } { m m m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \exp_args:NnnV \NewDocumentCommand { ##1 } { #2 } \l_tmpa_tl
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommands { \powerset, \Powerset, \PowerSet } {} { \mathcal{P} }

\NewDocumentCommands { \mat, \bmat } { m } { \begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix} }

\begin{document}

$\powerset\Powerset\PowerSet$

$\mat{a\\b}+\bmat{a\\b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]